# cellForRowAtIndexPath stops being called after the initial visible cells are drawn

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm working a on viewController that acts as a chat room using Parse as a backend. cellForRowAtIndexPath is only called for the initially visible cells (so 7 or 8 times) then when I scroll down the table view the space is there but it is all blank and cellForRowAtIndexPath is not being called anymore. The count of the array is correct and all of the data is retrieved. The most confusing part is that sometimes it works properly on the first load then at other times the problem occurs. Thanks in advance for the help. Here are my tableView delegate methods:

```
#pragma mark - Table View Delegate Methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [self.chatData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
ChatCell *cell = (ChatCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"chatCellIdentifier"];

NSUInteger row = [self.chatData count]-[indexPath row]-1;


if (row < [self.chatData count]) {

    NSString *chatText = [[self.chatData objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"text"];
    NSString *theUserName = [[self.chatData objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"userName"];
    PFFile *imageFile = [[self.chatData objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"avatar"];

    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13.0];
    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font forKey:NSFontAttributeName];

    NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:chatText attributes:attributes];


    CGRect rect = [chatText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(225.0f, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                      options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading
                                   attributes:attributes
                                      context:nil];
    CGSize size = rect.size;

    cell.textString.frame = CGRectMake(76, 23, size.width +20, size.height + 20);
    cell.textString.textAlignment = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    NSDate *theDate = [[self.chatData objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"date"];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm a"];
    NSString *timeString = [formatter stringFromDate:theDate];

    cell.textString.attributedText = attrString;
    [cell.textString sizeToFit];
    cell.timeLabel.text = timeString;
    cell.userLabel.text = theUserName;
    cell.userAvatar.file = imageFile;
}


return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *cellText = [[self.chatData objectAtIndex:self.chatData.count-indexPath.row-1] objectForKey:@"text"];

UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13.0];
CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(225.0f, MAXFLOAT);

CGRect boundingRect = [cellText boundingRectWithSize:constraintSize
                                         options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                      attributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:cellFont, NSFontAttributeName, nil]
                                         context:nil];

return boundingRect.size.height + 40;
}
```

Comment: After you call dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier, you need to make sure it returns a valid cell (cell == nil), or else you will have to allocate one.

Comment: @rocky, this is not necessary if the cell was made in a storyboard, or you registered either a class or a nib for the cell. Besides, if it was necessary to allocate the cells, then the OP's code wouldn't have shown any cells at all.

Comment: The cell was made in a storyboard with a subclass of UITableViewCell.

Comment: Could you post numberOfSections and numberOfRowsInSection, maybe some NSLog output showing what values those return?  The code that isn't being called probably won't contain very good clues as to why not.

Comment: I deleted numberOfSections and numberOfRowsInSection is outputting the correct count of the array. Right now it's something like 32, but cellForRowAtIndexPath is only called 8 times. Let me know if there is anything else you want to see. I've been stuck on this for awhile.

Comment: You'd better show all the UITableViewDataSource delegate method out.

Comment: I added all the table view delegate methods. Also, I should note that I'm using a table view in a UIViewController, not a UITableViewController. Thanks guys.

Comment: You guys have an idea or need more code?

Answer (score 1):

cellForRowAtIndexPath is only called to display the visible rows.  It is not called for every row.  You can have 1000's of rows, but this will only get called for the rows on screen.

Comment: When I scroll down it's not being called anymore. The space is there but it's all blank.

Comment: Sorry, I miss understood your question.